# How to authenticate delphi rest server with XMLHttpRequest?

Tags: javascript, delphi, rest, authentication, datasnap

I need help here. I've created a basic Delphi rest template using the wizard and setup a simple authentication method using the AuthenticationManager.

```
procedure TWebModule1.DSAuthenticationManager1UserAuthenticate(
  Sender: TObject; const Protocol, Context, User, Password: string;
  var valid: Boolean; UserRoles: TStrings);

begin

  valid := (user = 'username') and (password = 'password')

end;
```

Now I need to pass both the username and password to this server from a JavaScript client through invoking one of the server methods. I've tried the following three ways:

```
request = new XMLHttpRequest();
request.open('GET','http://username:password@localhost:8080/datasnap/rest/TServerMethods1/ReverseString/blah', true);
```

,

```
request = new XMLHttpRequest();
request.open('GET','http://localhost:8080/datasnap/rest/TServerMethods1/ReverseString/blah', true, 'username', 'password');
```

and

```
request = new XMLHttpRequest();
request.open('GET','http://username:password@localhost:8080/datasnap/rest/TServerMethods1/ReverseString/blah', true);
request.setRequestHeader("Authorization", "Basic " + StringToBase64("username:password"));
```

None of them works. They all returned 401 errors. Any ideas?

Comment: What is the "WEB" server used in DataSnap? Is it based on Indy or is ISAPI dll, plugged into IIS?

Comment: It's an independent server.

Comment: What happens if you open "http://localhost:8080/datasnap/rest/TServerMethods1/ReverseString/blah" in a web browser? Does the authentication dialog box appear? If yes - are you able to authenticate successfully?

Comment: Yes. There will be a small dialog box prompt for username and password in my Chrome browser and I was able to login and invoke the ReverseString method successfully. If I want to get the login box again I have to restart my browser.

Comment: Sorry for double post. Is there any other ways to implement authentication protocol for rest server beside using the default manager? I'm not very familiar with Delphi datasnap.

Comment: Can you check what is the value of WWW-Authenticate header, sent by the web server? I think it's possible to do this using Chrome's Developer Tools toolbar (F12). Then go to Networking tab.

Comment: I have two theories: 1) authentication schemes mismatch - the server offers different auth. scheme than the client uses. 2) Something is wrong with your user/password. By the way you use StringToBase64. This function encodes UTF16 string (Delphi >= 2009 the string is Unicode /UTF16LE/), but the browser may expect the encoded string to be UTF8 (Base64_Encode returns different strings when you encode UTF8 and UTF16 strings). Please, check this also.

Comment: The string "Aladdin:open sesame" (without double quotes) should return "QWxhZGRpbjpvcGVuIHNlc2FtZQ==". What does your StringToBase64() return on this?

Comment: Yes, the string matches. It appears that my delphi rest server doesn't like when I encode a header to javascript xmlhttprequest. I encode the same authentication header using PHP file_get_contents($url, false, $header) and it works. But not with Javascript :/